# Exclude comments from ID data base

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using gid to find symbols/functions in a pre made ID database "mkid".
Unfortunately, I see references to functions in comments when searching for these functions.
For example: When searching for function func(), one of the results could be:

```
source_file.c:1664:} /* end func() */
```

How to exclude all comments from being included in the database search?